# Controller not being discovered in asp.net core F#

Tags: asp.net-core, f#

I am trying to setup a unit test in F# with asp.net core. with the code below.  but the code to the server fails with a 404 Not found. 
Is there a reason why the controller is being discovered by the framework ?

```
module Tests

open System
open Xunit
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
open Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

type Startup ()  = 
    member  __.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) =
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2) |> ignore

    member __.Configure(app: IApplicationBuilder, env: IHostingEnvironment) = 
        app.UseMvc() |> ignore

[<Route("api")>]
[<ApiController>]
type TestController() =
    inherit ControllerBase()

    [<HttpGet("testGet")>]
    member __.TestGet() =
        121221

    [<HttpPost("testPost")>]
    member __.TestPost() =
        String.Empty

let buildHost(baseAdress:string) =
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost
                .CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls(baseAdress)
                .Build()

[<Fact>]
let ``My test`` () =
    let baseAdress = "https://localhost:9000"
    use host = buildHost(baseAdress)
    host.RunAsync() |> ignore
    let client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(BaseAddress = new System.Uri(baseAdress))
    let result = client.GetAsync("api/testGet").Result
    Assert.Equal(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode)
    Assert.True(result.IsSuccessStatusCode, result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result )
```

Here is the content of the fsproj File

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Tests.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Change the project SDK element to use `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`.

Comment: changing the project SDK to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web does not help

Comment: Is it also possible that the host isn't starting in time to handle the request you throw at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Except the reasons commented above by [@Kirk Larkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630078/kirk-larkin), you need put your controller into a `namespace` instead of `module` directly.

   ```ml
   namespace App         //<------------- put your controller into a namespace

   // ... open 

   type Startup ()  = 
       ...

   [<Route("api")>]
   [<ApiController>]
   type TestController() =
       ...

   module Tests= 
       // ... open

       let buildHost(baseAdress:string) =
           Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost
               .CreateDefaultBuilder()
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
               .UseUrls(baseAdress)
               .Build()

       [<Fact>]
       let ``My test`` () =
           ...
   ```
2. Also note you're starting the server by an asynchronous method `host.RunAsync() |> ignore`. Although the above test code works fine for me, there's a chance your `HttpClient` will send requests before the server is ready. A good way is to add a reference to the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost/2.2.0) package and using the built-in **`TestHost`** instead:

   ```
    let hostBuilder = 
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost
            .CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
    use server = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer(hostBuilder)
    use client = server.CreateClient()
    let result = client.GetAsync("api/testGet").Result    // a quick & dirty test 
    Assert.Equal(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode)
    Assert.True(result.IsSuccessStatusCode, result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result )
   ```

---

**[Edit]**:

I'm now sure it is a behavior by design. See [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Controllers/ControllerFeatureProvider.cs#L53-L55):

> ```
>         // We only consider public top-level classes as controllers. IsPublic returns false for nested
>         // classes, regardless of visibility modifiers
>         if (!typeInfo.IsPublic)
>         {
>             return false;
>         }
> ```

Since the class within a F# module will be compiled into a **nested** class, it won't be considered as a Controller at all.

Answer (score 2):

On top of the answer that [@itminus](https://stackexchange.com/users/13973727/itminus) provided. the issue can be resolved by configuring the application manager in configureServices like so

```
    member  this.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) =
        services
            .AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(fun m -> 
                m.FeatureProviders.Add
                     {
                        new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFeatureProvider() with 
                            member __.IsController (typeInfo:System.Reflection.TypeInfo) = 
                                        (typeof<ControllerBase>.IsAssignableFrom(typeInfo)) || base. IsController(typeInfo) 
                     }
            ) |> ignore
        services.AddRouteAnalyzer() |> ignore
```

Comment: Brilliant approach